# (Delphi) query.next not working

Tags: delphi, tadoquery

I need help to fix my code...

I try to build some application with this code

```
Adoquery.close;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('select * from schedule where every like ''%5%''');
ADOQuery1.Open;

if not ADOQuery1.Eof then
  begin
  ShowMessage('hallo '+ADOQuery1.fieldbyname('remark').AsString);
  ADOQuery1.Next;
  end
Else
  Begin
  end;
```

I have 2 data records for the result, but why only one remark is showing?

I try to Trace it and found problem in ADOQuery1.next. After my application read ADOQuery.next, cursor jump to

```
end;
```

not go back to

```
if not ADOQuery1.Eof then
```

.

Any mistakes with my code?

Comment: You should use a `while` like `while not ADOQuery1.Eof do`

Comment: Additional, you should also make your cursor to be on the first record before iterating like this `ADOQuery1.First;`

Comment: @Fero68, yes that is a good habit to get into, but unnecessary immediately after a call to `Open`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The execution does not go back to the if statement because the code does not say to do so. You have a single if statement and no iteration. You need to iterate. For instance with a while loop:

```
while not ADOQuery1.Eof do begin
  // do something
  ADOQuery1.Next;
end;
```